# linear program-Simplex method-Dual problem

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, two-phase-simplex

At an exercise I am asked to solve a linear program using the simplex method(in Matlab).Then I have to formulate the dual of this problem and read off an optimal solution of the dual problem from the final tableau of Simplex. 
What do I have to do? I have done the Simplex method and found the final tableau. But what is meant with "*read off an optimal solution of the dual problem from the final tableau of Simplex*"?

Comment: The $z_j-c_j$ of the slack/surplus variables in the final table should give you the solution of the dual.

Comment: A ok! For example having $z_2-c_2=1$, $z_3-c_3=1$, $z_5-c_5=2$,  (the other columns are basic), which is the answer? $w_2=1$, $w_3=1$, $w_5=2$ ? Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: Columns corresponding to slack/surplus variables should be considered regardless of whether they are basic. It will help if you post your problem.

Comment: I hope you can [this picture](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~rrizzi/classes/LP/esercizi/tableauTutorial/img42.gif)